# How to migrate core data model from 'xcdatamodel' to 'xcdatamodeld'?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, magicalrecord, core-data-migration

I am using core data in `XCode 11` with the `MagicalRecord` library. My records are lost after app update. I have also tried to migrate the core data model from `xcdatamodel` to `xcdatamodeld`. Has anyone else faced the same issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:"xcdatamodeld"]`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. It is a bug in magical record. You don't need to name your sqlite store like "xcdatamodeld". Any name will be ok.

I made a pull request https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/pull/1378

You can replace the line in `Podfile` if you like

`pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/expkzb/MagicalRecord'`

Have a try please.